# Problem with redirect to other pages using URI

Tags: php

I am stuck with the URI which is not redirected to the pages which I made. I have pages

1. about.php
2. about-culture.php
3. contact.php
4. index.php

index page works fine but when I try to redirect to other pages it throws the exception

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: No route defined for this URI. in /opt/lampp/htdocs/learnPHP/core/Router.php:21 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/learnPHP/index.php(6): Router->direct('about/about/cul...') #1 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/learnPHP/core/Router.php on line 21
```

If the question is not understandable I also record the video to describe my problem.
https://www.useloom.com/share/5199399f3b5f42dd9c589a47dad0738f

I try a lot of things made the change in the code. When I var_dump() to uri function it returns me the multiple links which are the wrong URI

my routes.php file

```
<?php
$router->define([
    '' => 'controllers/index.php',
    'about' => 'controllers/about.php',
    'about/culture' => 'controllers/about-culture.php',
    'contact' => 'controllers/contact.php'
]);
```

index.php

```
$database = require 'core/bootstrap.php';

require Router::load('routes.php')
    ->direct(Request::uri());
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
AddType text/css .css
AddType text/javascript .js
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [END]
```

Request.php

```
<?php
class Request
{
    public static function uri()
    {

      $uri = (substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],10));
      $removeSlash = rtrim($uri, '/');
      return var_dump($removeSlash);

    }
}
```

```
Router.php
<?php

class Router
{
    protected $routes = [];
    public static function load($file)
    {
        $router = new static;
        require $file;
        return $router;
    }
    public function define($routes)
    {
        $this->routes = $routes;
    }
    public function direct($uri)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($uri, $this->routes)) {
            return $this->routes[$uri];
        }
        throw new Exception('No route defined for this URI.');
    }
}

 ?>
```

Please click on the link to see the resulting image https://prnt.sc/n3ar12

Comment: Which framework are you using?

Comment: Hi 
thanks for your replay. I am not using any framework it is a cure php I follow the series 
https://laracasts.com/series/php-for-beginners

and the problem occurs in video number 17 Dry Up Your Views
video link

https://laracasts.com/series/php-for-beginners/episodes/17


Is anything more to share if you want

thanks

Comment: please check video maybe you understant the problem https://www.useloom.com/share/5199399f3b5f42dd9c589a47dad0738f

Comment: if you want to see the code 
https://github.com/hassanshahzadaheer/phpbasic

Answer (score 0):

It looks like within your navigation shown in your video you are doing a

```
<a href="">Home</a>
```

instead of a

```
<a href="/learnPHP/">Home</a>
```

Please find more about relative and absolute urls at https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

You need to edit your views/partials/nav.php and link the correct home path which in your case is '/learnPHP/' as you are using the learnPHP subfolder or would be '/' if not using a subfolder. I do also highly recommend to use urls with a beginning '/' for all your other navigation items.

Comment: Hi! friend thank you so much

I did this before but not work is some other way to solve this problem 
I am very thankful to you

Comment: Hi you’re welcome! Please vote up or mark this answer as selected if it solved your problem. Good luck learning PHP :)

Comment: I am still facing the same problem bro. I clone the code which the authour wrote and published on GitHub but nothing get change.
here the author code
https://github.com/laracasts/The-PHP-Practitioner-Episode-16